# Excel VBA: Copy and paste shapes at same position

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I want to copy all shapes from one worksheet and paste them on another worksheet at the same position. The shapes can be rectangular callouts or pictures.

So far, I know how to loop through all shapes in my old worksheet:

`Dim s As Shape
For each s in Activesheet.Shapes
...
Next`

How do I copy and paste the shapes at the same position in another worksheet, say Sheets("new")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below code should get you going. Be aware that I'm using the internal sheet name in the code. (`Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. The names before the brackets in the Project Explorer)

I used a bit of a workaround to avoid working with selections: You need to set the name of the shape first, because if it still has the standard name (e.g. "Oval 3") the name gets changed ("Oval 4"). In the end you can restore the original name of the shapes in both sheets.

```
Sub CopyShapes()

    Dim s As Shape
    Dim OriginalName As String

    For Each s In Sheet1.Shapes
        OriginalName = s.Name
        s.Name = "FixedName"
        s.Copy
        Sheet2.Paste
        Sheet2.Shapes("FixedName").Top = s.Top
        Sheet2.Shapes("FixedName").Left = s.Left
        s.Name = OriginalName
        Sheet2.Shapes("FixedName").Name = OriginalName
    Next s

End Sub
```

**Edit:** Adjusted the code to avoid the use of `Selection.` as required in the comments

Comment: Sorry, wrong shot, it does not work. I get an error message that I cant modify the "top" property of a range-object. Apparently "selection" does not give me the handle for the shape object.

Comment: I adjusted the code in my answer to avoid the use of `Selection.`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is no specific method to copy all of them.  You could try the regular `.Copy Destination:=...` method, but I'm not positive this will work.

The alternative is to just generate a new shape on the new sheet with identical properties to the desired shape.  As you loop through the shapes on your current sheet, you would just need to create new shape objects with all of the same properties.

The most effective method (although this depends slightly on your intentions) is just to copy the original worksheet, instead of generating a fresh sheet.  This will pull all the shapes (and other data) to the new sheet with all location and properties kept identical.  If you just need the shapes and none of the cell data, you can copy the sheet and then add `NewSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents` which will remove all the data but leave formatting intact.

Comment: You can also just use `.Clear` if you don't want to preserve formatting

Comment: To copy the shapes does not really suit me needs: I have a template in Excel, where the layout changes from time to time. The script shall transfer all the information from the old templates (about 150) to the new template format including annotations that come in the form of callouts.

Comment: @derMax I'm confused.  You need to copy more than the shapes or only the shapes?

Comment: The template is kind of a userform, where most information is stored in the cells. All cells that are not intended to be edited by the user are locked. I need to transfer all the information from editable cells as well as all shapes on the chart. I already did the first task - now the shapes are what I havent achieved so far.

Comment: @derMax Well using the third method i suggested would do all of that for you, but if not, try the second method.  Did you try it and it didn't work for you?

Comment: The third method did not work - I have some merged cells, and apparently copying does not work well here.
I also thought of the second method, but is not applicable since I also have pictures...

Comment: @derMax copying a sheet would preserve everything, including merged cells

Comment: ok, let me check. Your idea might ruin the work of my morning. You mean simply with sheets.copy?

Comment: @derMax yes.  Copy the sheet first and then change what you need to for the new template, rather than making a new sheet and copying all the individual items over

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. But I have various changes in the new template, including different conditional formatting styles, different formulas etc... Changing that inside VBA is possible, but a nightmare. Thus so far, I have an empty template where the formatting is already done and copy the content.

Comment: @derMax then I would recommend cycling through the shapes and creating new ones with all properties identical, as suggested in my second method.

Comment: :) Which is a good idea, apart from the fact that I have pictures that I cant simply recreate. I will go for the other answer, as this works well as I can see so far. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, the other answer did not really work. I will try some other things and get back to you as soon as I know how to do it